# How to correct connection positions programmatically?

Tags: bpmn.io

When we move an element, bpmnjs tries to improve the way other elements connect to that element (by changing its connection's way-points after we drop the element I guess).

Now imagine I have some bpmn diagrams which have untidy connections. How can I do that correction on all connections after loading?

Comment: The connection-rendering itself is handled via the internally used [diagram-js library](https://github.com/bpmn-io/diagram-js).